# Produce a grouping based on if a period occurs between a start and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are many examples coming up on StackOverflow, but they all seem to slightly different questions - or at least the ones I can fine.

I have a table of items with a start date and and end date occurring sometime in the next 10 years.
The end result I am trying to achieve is which of these items occur in which quarter?

Here's my source

```
item   |StartDate    |  EndDate     |
Item#1 | 2022-01-04  |  2022-07-01  |
Item#2 | 2022-04-01  |  2022-06-20  |
```

So extracting the quarter is easy with

```
DATEPART(QUARTER, StartDate)
DATEPART(QUARTER, FinishDate)
```

and I have a table of all the quarters, as in a quarter is defined by a start date and an end date.

```
QuarterLabel | Start      |  End      |
Quarter 1    | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31|
Quarter 2    | 2022-04-01 | 2022-08-01|
etc
```

But how do I determine whether that item is just in quarter 1? or maybe spans quarter 1 and 2?

My goal is to create something like this:

```
Client       |  Quarter 1   | Quarter 2        | Quarter 3 | ....
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
CustomerA    | Item#1       |  Item#1          |           |
CustomerB    |              |  Item#1, Item#2  |  Item#2   |
```

My best guess, which got me nowhere:

```
SELECT 
Item,
CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, StartDate) as float) +
CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, StartDate) <3 THEN cast((DATEPART(QUARTER, StartDate) + 2) as float) /10
    WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, StartDate) >2 THEN cast((DATEPART(QUARTER, StartDate) - 2) as float) /10
    ELSE 0
END as StartQuarterNumber,

CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, FinishDate) as float) +
CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, FinishDate) <3 THEN cast((DATEPART(QUARTER, FinishDate) + 2) as float) /10
    WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, FinishDate) >2 THEN cast((DATEPART(QUARTER, FinishDate) - 2) as float) /10
    ELSE 0
END as FinishQuarterNumber
FROM table1
```

MS SQL Server 11.0.7

Comment: Done. The problem is I have absolutely no idea how to solve it.

Comment: Looks like you need to join your data with your quarters table and pivot. Some more varied and covering sample data would be useful. Also knowing your SQL Server version would be handy.

Comment: Definitely no need for floats.

Comment: Here is your join condition: `inner join Quarters q on StartDate >= q.Start and FinishDate <= q."End"`

Comment: What is "Period" supposed to be?  Also, in your expected output, why are there 2 rows containing "item#1"? If that's not a typo (or some requirement I overlooked) please try and make sure your "expected results" align with the sample data :-)

Comment: Your desired results now includes a "Client" which appears neither in your sample data nor your query attempt...

Comment: That exactly my question.... . Item one has a duration spanning multiple quarters. So I need to translates "starting 1 April" and "finishing 1 Aug" as spanning two quarters.

Comment: @shawnt00 if I may, having working with so many different scenarios of this type the proper join would be `inner join Quarters q on StartDate <= q."End" and FinishDate >= q.Start` reason being in your join it will only works for whatever is within StartDate/FinishDate. But it will not work for the edge cases in which q.Start is  < StartDate and q.End > StartDate, which should. Essentially this: https://imgur.com/UczLYzR

Comment: @Jorge Campos - your image is exactly right.

Comment: (edit) Are the quarter label values unique? Because that will impact a pivot .... Also, it'd be much easier to assist  if the sample data was more complete and actually aligned with the expected results (and you'd probably have an answer already) :-)

Comment: `inner join Quarters q on StartDate <= q."End" and FinishStart >= q.Start`

Answer (score 1):

Here we use a recursive CTE to make a list of years from `year(min(start_date))` to `year(max(end_date))`.  We then join this list to the table events and group by year, using `string_agg`to list the projects active during each quarter of that year.
I have prefered to present the 4 quarters as columns and the years as row for 2 reasons :

- It seems much clearer as presentation. If the data extends of several years you could have dozens of quarters.
- It avoids having a dynamique number of columns.

You speak of clients but their are no clients in your sample data. We could easily add client in the list of fields selected and in the group by, which would create a line per client per year that they have a project.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE events (
>   ID VARCHAR(10),
>   start_date DATE,
>   end_date DATE);
> INSERT INTO events VALUES
> ('item#1','20190101','20201231'),
> ('item#2','20200315','20200601'),
> ('item#3','20200706','20200802'),
> ('item#4','20201201','20201230'),
> ('item#5','20200601','20210120');
> GO
> ```

5 rows affected

> 

> ```
> with years as
>   (select 
>      year(max(end_date)) fyear,
>      year(min(start_date)) syear
>    from events
>   union all
>    select
>      fyear,
>      syear + 1
>    from years
>    where syear < fyear
>   )
> select
>   y.syear "Year" ,
>    string_agg( case when start_date <= concat(syear,'0331') 
>                 and end_date>= concat(syear,'0101')
>                 then e.id end , ',') Q1,
>    string_agg( case when start_date <= concat(syear,'0630') 
>                 and end_date>= concat(syear,'0401')
>                 then e.id end , ',') Q2,
>    string_agg( case when start_date <= concat(syear,'0930') 
>                 and end_date>= concat(syear,'0701')
>                 then e.id end , ',') Q3,
>    string_agg( case when start_date <= concat(syear,'1231') 
>                 and end_date>= concat(syear,'1001')
>                 then e.id end , ',') Q4                
> from
>   years y
> join events e
>   on year(end_date) >= syear
>   and year(start_date) <= syear
> group by syear
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Year | Q1            | Q2                   | Q3                   | Q4                  
> ---: | :------------ | :------------------- | :------------------- | :-------------------
> 2019 | item#1        | item#1               | item#1               | item#1              
> 2020 | item#1,item#2 | item#1,item#2,item#5 | item#1,item#3,item#5 | item#1,item#4,item#5
> 2021 | item#5        | null                 | null                 | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=030942dcda40485e4a551d5756c989b3)*

Comment: Thank you. that is a very well explained solution, and a very useful bit of code. great as a summary of the data, but it's not exactly the summary that I require. I think I'll have another go and post a question that tries to answer the (fair) criticisms  of my question